# Turn keys and values of an object into array of objects

Tags: javascript

so I have a data structure that looks like this :

```
data = {
  a: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  b: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
  c: ["123", "235423", "12312", "1231", "12312"],
  d: ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee"],
  ...
}
```

and I need to convert it into a following structure:

```
[
   { a: 1, b: "a", c: "123", d: "aa", ... },
   { a: 2, b: "b", c: "235423", d: "bb", ... },
   { a: 3, b: "c", c: "12312", d: "cc", ... },
   { a: 4, b: "d", c: "1231", d: "dd", ... },
   { a: 5, b: "a", c: "12312", d: "ee", ... },
]
```

the number of keys in `data` can vary, but the length of the values will always be same across all arrays, i.e. `data[a].length === data[z].length` will always be true.

My solution:

```
const doStuff = () => {
    const result = [];
    const keys = Object.keys(data);

    if (!keys) return result;

    const valuesLength = keys[0].length
    const result = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < valuesLength ; i++) {
        const obj = {};
        for (const key in data) {
            obj[key] = data[key][i];
        }

        result.push(obj);
    }
    return result;
};
```

is using two for loops is not most effective one since the number of keys can be large, so i'm looking for a most optimal solution

Comment: It is going to be two loops. Show your solution.

Comment: @epascarello updated

Answer (score 1):

You may traverse your source object keys ([`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)) with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), looping inner arrays with [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and assigning corresponding property of resulting object:

```js
const src = {a:[1,2,3,4,5],b:["a","b","c","d","e"],c:["123","235423","12312","1231","12312"],d:["aa","bb","cc","dd","ee"]},

      result = Object
        .keys(src)
        .reduce((acc, key, i, keys) => {
          src[key].forEach((v, j) => {
            acc[j] = acc[j] || {}
            acc[j][key] = v
          })
          return acc
        }, [])
        
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

By assuming same length arrays, you could get the entries and reduce the array by mapping all values along with the object at the same index and the new property.

```js
const
    data = { a: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], b: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], c: ["123", "235423", "12312", "1231", "12312"], d: ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee"] },
    result = Object
        .entries(data)
        .reduce((r, [k, a]) => a.map((v, i) => ({ ...r[i], [k]: v })), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: right. it need same length arrays, which op is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is going to require two loops. One to go over the properties in the object, the other to loop over the array of values.

Personally I would use reduce and forEach for the two loops

```js
const data = {
  a: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  b: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
  c: ["123", "235423", "12312", "1231", "12312"],
  d: ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee"]
}

const result = Object.entries(data).reduce((arr, [key, values]) => (
  values.forEach((value, index) => {
    arr[index] = {
      ...arr[index],
      [key]: value
    };
  }),
  arr), []);

console.log(result);
```

without the fat arrows and destructuring

```js
var data = {
  a: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  b: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
  c: ["123", "235423", "12312", "1231", "12312"],
  d: ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee"]
};

var result = Object.entries(data).reduce(function(result, entry) {
  var key = entry[0];
  var arr = entry[1];

  arr.forEach(function(value, index) {
    result[index] = result[index] || {};
    result[index][key] = value;
  });

  return result;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code:

```
var data = {
  a: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  b: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
  c: ["123", "235423", "12312", "1231", "12312"],
  d: ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee"]
}
  
var anotherObjArray = [];

  for(var i=0;i<data[Object.keys(data)[0]].length;i++){
    let tempObj = {};
    for(var j=0;j<Object.keys(data).length;j++){
        tempObj[Object.keys(data)[j]] = data[Object.keys(data)[j]][i];    
    }
    anotherObjArray.push(tempObj);
  }
```

anotherObjArray is the final array for your requirement.

Comment: thats basically the same that i have

Comment: @testing_kate Yeah, basically almost same except the inner for loop which I iterated over an array instead of object. Because iterating over array is most preferred one than an object.